# How to position caret in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, dropdown, popper.js

I'm trying to position the caret to the right so it doesn't move when I select an option.

```js
$('#dropdownMenu span').on('click', function() {
                $('#dropdownMenuButton').html($(this).text());
            });
```

```css
#dropdownMenuButton {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 30vw;
  text-align:left;
}

#dropdownMenu {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px)!important;
  width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>bootstrap dropdown</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select boats
                </button>
    <div id='dropdownMenu' class="dropdown-menu" >
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Avrora</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Irlbach</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Laura</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Lola </span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Syrena</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Thea</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Anne</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Bebe</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Camilla</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Emma</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Katy</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Nelli</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Winter</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Aeolus</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Amorina</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Melina</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Nieva</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Nora</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Rush</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Alex</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Blue J</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Corker</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>DaCapo</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Freedom</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Golden</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Montana</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Moonshadow</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Phoebe</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Ra</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Rigel</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Santuzza</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Sorccerer</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Stiletto</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Tony</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Wasabi</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

adding the following:

.dropdown-toggle::after{
margin-top:1vw;
float:right;
}

```js
$('#dropdownMenu span').on('click', function() {
                $('#dropdownMenuButton').html($(this).text());
            });
```

```css
#dropdownMenuButton {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 30vw;
  text-align:left;
}

#dropdownMenu {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px)!important;
  width: 30vw;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after{
    margin-top:1vw;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>bootstrap dropdown</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select boats
                </button>
    <div id='dropdownMenu' class="dropdown-menu" >
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Avrora</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Irlbach</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Laura</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Lola </span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Syrena</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Thea</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Anne</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Bebe</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Camilla</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Emma</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Katy</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Nelli</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Winter</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Aeolus</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Amorina</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Melina</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Nieva</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Nora</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Rush</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Alex</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Blue J</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Corker</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>DaCapo</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Freedom</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Golden</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Montana</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Moonshadow</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Phoebe</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Ra</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Rigel</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Santuzza</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Sorccerer</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Stiletto</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Tony</span>
      <span class='dropdown-item'>Wasabi</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.sailwbob.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix it on the right side with absolute position

```css
#dropdownMenuButton {
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 30vw;
    text-align: left;

    /* add relative position */
    position: relative;

}
#dropdownMenuButton::after {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: .255em;
    vertical-align: .255em;
    content: "";
    border-top: .3em solid;
    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: .3em solid transparent;

    /* add these code */
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```